# missing EOF at '-keepclass' proguard android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

when I add one line in proguard file its showing error Error:com.android.build.gradle.shrinker.parser.ProguardParserException: ProGuard configuration parser error: /root/projectDirectory/myprojectname/app/proguard-rules.pro line 42:0 missing EOF at '-keepclass'.

If I remove this file it shows Error :
Method code too large.

The project builds successful without proguard.
Any suggestion ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're using an invalid rule with something like:

```
-keepclass com.example.activity {*;}
```

it should be

```
-keep class com.example.activity {*;}
```